# onActivityResult is not updating ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-glide, onactivityresult

I have an image which is coming from custom Gallery inside fragment's `onActivityresult`

Calling custom Gallery

```
Custom_Gallery custom_gallery=new Custom_Gallery();
custom_gallery.setTargetFragment(this,301);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.FragmentMain,custom_gallery).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Sending Result back to fragment from Custom Gallery

```
bundle.putStringArrayList("Media",media);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras(bundle);
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(),getActivity().RESULT_OK,intent);
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

Getting result inside `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode==301 && resultCode==getActivity().RESULT_OK){
        List<String> image=data.getStringArrayListExtra("Media");
        Log.d(TAG,"Image "+image.get(0));
        String img=image.get(0);
        //File uploadedImage = new File(image.get(0));
        /*Bitmap myImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.get(0));
            uploadImage.setImageBitmap(myImage);*/

        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(img)
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .error(R.drawable.add_fav)
            .dontAnimate()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .into(uploadImage);

        uploadButton.setEnabled(true);
        functions=new App_Functions(getActivity());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.get(0));
        String Base64Image=functions.Convert_To_Base64(bitmap);
        //Log.d(TAG,"Base 64 "+Base64Image);
    }
}
```

Here's the image path which I am getting from custom gallery inside Fragment's `onActivityResult`

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/Media/Images/Ximg1520693707996.jpg
```

I tried with Bitmap's decodefile method then set manually to `Imageview` but still not working i thought its Glide issue but its not even setting with Bitmap.

Imageview has onClicklistener and i wanted to set selected image to `ImageView`
[image]

Comment: Did you check if decodeFile() returned null? Is the mentioned path correct? You are not checking it.

Comment: I do not see any `setResult`. Are you sure that your `onActivityResult` is called properly from the calling fragment? Have you tried writing any log to check if the function in the `onActivityResult` is being called?

Comment: @greenapps As you can see in `onActivityresult` I am generating log, Which gives me image path which i mentioned above in last.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I am converting image into Base64 into `onActivityresult` which successfully showing into log. Also i am getting image path inside `onActivityresult`

Comment: Should not it be `Glide.with(getActivity()).load(image.get(0))`? I do not see any variable named `img` here.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Sorry i missed that now you can see `img` Variable

Comment: `I am generating log, Which gives me image path which i mentioned above in last.`. That is only a path. But you should check i that file exists. You did not do that. I asked you also to do so. So why didnt you? Further i asked you to check if decodeFile() returned null. Both requests you did not honor.

Comment: @greenapps i checked that path manually inside file explorer. It exist. for decode file i will update you within a min

Comment: @greenapps `Decode File android.graphics.Bitmap@a5d1b58`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with lifecycle of android ecosystem. As `onResume` calls after `onActivityResult`. All i need to save image path in `String` when getting result at `onActivityResult` then use it on set path in `ImageView` at `onResume`

Comment: thank you very much, this solved my issue.... But is this also the right way to do it or is it bad practise? cause there might be some memory leaks?

Comment: @JenejFjrjdn i don't think it's a bad practice because of we are saving only a string in global variable and for me that fragment is destroy soon after image upload so string will also get collect by GC automatically because of string is immutable